# Puppeteer/BrowserShot: file not found but it exists

Tags: php, puppeteer, browsershot

I'm trying to use Puppeteer and BrowserShot on an Ubuntu machine to make and screenshot of a static HTML.

The thing is that every time I try to make and screenshot:

```php
Screenshot::loadView('monthly_resume.resume')
            ->waitUntilNetworkIdle(true)
            ->windowSize(1200, 630)
            ->noSandbox()
            ->storeAs($this->pathFor($user), 'image.php');
```

It returns an error. It seems that the HTML it's stored properly under a folder inside `/tmp`, in this case `tmp/441150534-0230735001662479158/index.html`.

But when node tries to find it says that the file it's not found even when it's there. **Any idea why node can't find it?**

```bash
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException

The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/home/forge/monse.app/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"file:\/\/\/tmp\/441150534-0230735001662479158\/index.html","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"\/tmp\/1562301876-0230606001662479158\/BrowsershotOutput1662479158hbgfB.png","args":["--no-sandbox"],"viewport":{"width":1200,"height":630},"displayHeaderFooter":false,"waitUntil":"networkidle0"}}'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /home/forge/monse.app

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
Error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND at file:///tmp/441150534-0230735001662479158/index.html
    at navigate (/home/forge/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:225:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Frame.goto (/home/forge/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:195:21)
    at async Page.goto (/home/forge/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1143:16)
    at async callChrome (/home/forge/monse.app/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:249:26)
```

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. Can you share a [mcve], directory structure and steps to reproduce this? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question, but the problems seems to be that npm/node can't find a file under /tmp even when it's there 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered exact error message that you got. But then I just change temp path and its working fine. I'm using `spatie/browsershot` by the way

To change temp path at `spatie/browsershot`:

```
Browsershot::html('some html string')
   ->setCustomTempPath('/home/your/other/path')
   ->save('filename.jpg')
```